# SELECT id_field WHERE max(date_field) < 'some date'

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sure this question is obvious, but I've been fiddling with an increasingly complex set of subqueries for the last hour or so and getting nowhere.

I need to select a bunch of ID's from a table where the last date for that record is before a given date. I was trying:

```
SELECT id_field WHERE max(date_field) < 'some date'
```

But getting 'can't have aggregate in where field'. I've considered that I could SELECT where there are no dates above a certain date, but at this point my brain is waving it's little white flag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id_field 
  FROM tbl 
 GROUP BY id_field 
HAVING max(date_field) < 'some date'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id_field
     , max(date_field)
  FROM tbl
GROUP BY id_field
HAVING max(date_field) < 'some date'
```

Comment: You don't actually need to return max(date_field) to use it in the HAVING clause. It's basically correct (although most systems will complain that you haven't named the second field), but doesn't quite hit the mark according to what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.  `HAVING` is like a where for grouped values.